# AngularJS error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS: v1.5.11

Im trying to display images from a JSON array.

Is this the proper way : `$scope.mainImage = $scope.template.images[0].name;`. This is the line in the error that it says cant read property of `images`.

**My Controller in templates.js file:**

```
.controller("TemplatesDetailsCtrl", ["$scope", "$routeParams", "$http", "$filter", function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $filter ){
    var templateId = $routeParams.templateID;
    $http.get("json/templates.json").success(function(data){
        $scope.template = $filter("filter")(data, function(d){
            return d.id == templateId;
        })[0];
        $scope.mainImage = $scope.template.images[0].name; //THIS IS LINE 30
    });
}]);
```

I'm trying to display the very first image from the array. So my HTML is:

```
<img class="img-full" src="img/{{mainImage}}">
```

Ben trying a lot and not able to display the image. Im getting this error: 
[image]

Please help.

Comment: need to do some basic debugging... what does `$routeParams.templateID` return? What does `$scope.template` return? What does data look like? you clearly aren't getting what you expect in `$scope.template` so you need to dig in to find out why

Comment: You. I like you. I did a `console.log(templateId)` right after i defined the `var templateId` and got the same error. I mis-spelled `$routeParams.templateID`. Changing it to `$routeParams.templateId` worked. Thanks. I was trying this for a long time.

Comment: There you go...never assume that everything prior is what you expect it to be without checking

Comment: How do I mark your comment as answer?

Comment: it's really not an answer since it  is just basic debugging steps. A typo in your code really doesn't justify a full answer

Answer (score 1):

Seems like 'template' object is undefined. You can test for `undefined` before trying to use its properties **:**

```
if ($scope.template)
   $scope.mainImage = $scope.template.images[0].name; //THIS IS LINE 30
```

Comment: You are misinterpreting error ... template is undefined , not a property of it